# Consecutive same lines are squashed into one in journal

Tags: systemd, logs, systemd-journald, journalctl

I am running as below:

```
% systemd-run --user python3 -c "print(1);print(1)"
Running as unit: run-r9210c54561b84cdbaf4e741f5d2f3e57.service
```

I was expecting to see two 1s in each line. But I am seeing only one 1. But when printing different text, they work fine.

```
Jan 16 21:47:35 HOSTNAME systemd[30228]: Started /usr/bin/python3 -c print(1);print(2).
Jan 16 21:47:35 HOSTNAME python3[89226]: 1
Jan 16 21:47:35 HOSTNAME python3[89226]: 2
Jan 16 21:47:35 HOSTNAME systemd[30228]: run-ra947cd73cb164f208c863731013a261d.service: Succeeded.
```

---

```
Jan 16 21:47:41 HOSTNAME systemd[30228]: Started /usr/bin/python3 -c print(1);print(1).
Jan 16 21:47:41 HOSTNAME python3[89282]: 1
Jan 16 21:47:41 HOSTNAME systemd[30228]: run-r3c1ec5e8581d40a09081c64fdbcc689f.service: Succeeded.
```

---

```
Jan 16 22:13:07 HOSTNAME systemd[30228]: Started /usr/bin/python3 -c print("\n".join("1111112111111112111111111122111111")).
Jan 16 22:13:07 HOSTNAME python3[101884]: 1
Jan 16 22:13:07 HOSTNAME python3[101884]: 2
Jan 16 22:13:07 HOSTNAME python3[101884]: 1
Jan 16 22:13:07 HOSTNAME python3[101884]: 2
Jan 16 22:13:07 HOSTNAME python3[101884]: 1
Jan 16 22:13:07 HOSTNAME python3[101884]: 2
Jan 16 22:13:07 HOSTNAME python3[101884]: 1
Jan 16 22:13:07 HOSTNAME systemd[30228]: run-r7d461874552c4ddf923d05d02328a217.service: Succeeded.
```

Is this expected behavior? I couldn't find in documentation. Is there a way to fix this?